# Views and empty parameter in Path to link

Tags: views, nodes, uri

I know my title isn't explicit, but i will explain my problem. I created a view that displays me all documents(content) of my website, some documents are linked to a project(content) via entity reference, and in my `view` I display a link to a document. if there is a project the link looks like : `node/100?project=5` . If there is no project the link needs to look like : `node/100`.

So in my view I added field excluded from display with the id of the project, and a second field which is the id of the node document and I rewrite the link  to :

```
node/[nid]?project=[field_doc_project]
```

My problem is: This works fine for document with projects only. good url: `node/100?project=5` bad url, without project: `node/100?project=`.

Can I check in view if the project id exists and rewrite the url to `node/100`?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

almost there,

1. add a link to the original content as a field, exclude it from display
2. add a path to the original content as a field, exclude it from display
   [image: fields]
3. rewrite the term reference to the full url you want to have using replacements [path]?something=[someid]
   [image: reference url rewrite]
4. add a no results behavior and output the link from 1) [view_node]
   [image: no results behavior]